# Formula for nth term.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7,6,7,8,9,8,9,10,11$.

The pattern is that it goes in groups $(2,3,4,5)$ Same thing but shifted up 2 $(4,5,6,7)$, same thing $(6,7,8,9)$, and so on.

How would I go about finding the nth term this without using an online calculator?

Comment: try [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5Bn%2B4+-2floor%28%28n%2B4%29%2F4%29%2C+%7Bn%2C0%2C20%7D%5D)  
 $$(n+4) - 2\lfloor\frac{n+4}{4}\rfloor $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A(4k + 1) = 2k

A(4k + 2) = 2k+1

A(4k + 3) = 2k+2

A(4k + 4) = 2k+3

Therefore

$$ A(n) = 2 \cdot [\frac{n+3}{4}] + (n + 3 - [\frac{n+3}{4}] \cdot 4) $$

where [x] - integer part of x

Answer (score 1):

Notice the $4n+1$st term is always $2(n+1)$.

The first term ($4(0)+1$) is $2$ (otherwise known as $2(0+1)$)

The fifth term ($4(1)+1$) is $4$ (otherwise known as $2(1+1)$)

The ninth term ($4(2)+14$) is $6$ (otherwise known as $2(2+1)$)

and so on (you can prove it by induction if you like).

But then from here it is easy to get an explicit formula, since anything between these is just counting upwards!

So the final formula is

$$a_n = \begin{cases} 2(k+1) & n = 4k+1\\ 2(k+1)+1 & n = 4k+2\\ 2(k+1)+2 & n= 4k+3\\ 2(k+1)+3 & n=4k+4 \end{cases}$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^